# C# Abstract Func assignment (delegates)

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have the following abstract Func.

```
public abstract Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, int, TIndexed> IndexedObjectConstructor { get; }
```

My question is related to the implementation method.
1st: I create a method with the same signature

```
 public  IIndexedOhlcv Test(IEnumerable<IOhlcv> l, int i)
        {
            return new IndexedCandle(l, i);
        }
```

The, assign it to the Func.

```
 public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor = Test;
```

However, this shows an error

> Error CS0106  The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item

I know this can be solved using Lambda as following:

```
 public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor => Test;
```

Or

```
  public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor
           => (l, i) => new IndexedCandle(l, i);
```

My question is my the "IndexedObjectConstructor = Test;" does not work?

Comment: A [mcve] would be great here. I want to copy, paste, and compile your code.

Comment: why an abstract Func?

Comment: Why do you want a Func as abstract?

Comment: It's not an `abstract Func` - it's an `abstract` *property* that returns a `Func`.

Answer (score 2):

`IndexedObjectConstructor` is a get-only property that returns a `Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, int, TIndexed>`. In your attempted override, you're defining a field `IndexedObjectConstructor` that you're trying to initialize with `Test`.

Fields cannot be overridden (and even if they could be, its a property in the base class, not a field) and `Test`, by itself, isn't a property getter anyway.

When you implement it "with a lambda", you're using the relatively new [inline property declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn879355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the overriden thing is a property which means you must declare a `get` accessor when you override, which isn't done when you do

```
public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor = Test;
```

it also explains why the following works

```
public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor => Test;
```

Comment: What does the second one mean? is it similar to implement the get accessor only?

Comment: yes it is kind of a shortcut, there are other ways to do it such as 
`public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor { get => Test; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign a method to a property. You need to fully implement the `get`.

Your code needs to look like this:

```
public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor
{
    get
    {
        return (xs, i) => Test(xs, i);
    }
}
```

It is sufficient, however, to use the newer syntax like this:

```
public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor
{
    get => Test;
}
```

...or this:

```
public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor
    => Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complete working example.

```
public abstract class Test<TInput, TIndexed>
    {
        public abstract Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, int, TIndexed> IndexedObjectConstructor { get; }
    }

    public class Test1 : Test<IOhlcv, IIndexedOhlcv>
    {
        public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor
        {
            get
            {
                return TestMethod;                
            }
        }

        public IIndexedOhlcv TestMethod(IEnumerable<IOhlcv> l, int i)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public interface IOhlcv
    {

    }

    public interface IIndexedOhlcv
    {

    }
```

Now if you are asking why we have to implement property using getter. You can use different syntax. You can do following way to.

```
 public class Test1 : Test<IOhlcv, IIndexedOhlcv>
{
    public override Func<IEnumerable<IOhlcv>, int, IIndexedOhlcv> IndexedObjectConstructor => TestMethod;        

    public IIndexedOhlcv TestMethod(IEnumerable<IOhlcv> l, int i)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```